# Provision script in Laravel/Homestead

Tags: vagrant, provisioning, homestead

I wonder how I can include a provision script in Laravel/Homestead that should execute each time the Homestead VM is up.

As a hint, I used to work with Vagrant in following way,

`config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"`

where the `bootstrap.sh` file is my provision script.

Answer (score 1):

You can always manually force a provision with either `vagrant provision` or  `vagrant reload --provision`.

To make a every `vagrant up` automatically call the provisioner then simply define it in your Vagrantfile like so:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh",
    run: "always"
end
```

You can then choose to not run the provisioner by using the `vagrant up --no-provision`.

The [Vagrant docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html) on this go into a little more detail about what else you can do with provisioners.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Anyway, I think you misunderstood, I have done similarly in Vagrant. Currently the question is for Homestead. Homestead configuration are different from Vagrant.

Comment: Homestead runs on the top of Vagrant so I'm not too sure why this wouldn't work but I don't have Homestead set up right now to check. I know you at least still used the `vagrant ...` commands to control Homestead in cases like re-provisioning to add new sites but it's been a while since I touched it and not sure if that's changed since. In the case of doing `homestead up` it should just call `vagrant up` so if you have your Vagrantfile configured as above then it should work.

Comment: Sorry, It didn't work man. I added the Vagrantfile and put the provisions. Nothing happened.